# Deep comparing objects inside an array and finding duplicates

Tags: javascript, typescript, performance

What would be the most efficient way to deep compare objects inside an array and return the duplicates? I cannot compare by a property, the objects have to exactly the same.

The array will have hundreds of objects and performance is important.

I have thought of hashing the objects with a sha1 (or different) algorithm and then storing the hash as an additional property of the object and then comparing the hashes. Would that be a reliable way of pinpointing the duplicates?

Another option is doing 2 for loops with lodash isEqual but I am afraid that's not going to be fast enough. What are my options?

Comment: Should equality depend on key order?

Comment: @AndrewParks no, key order doesn't matter

Comment: I'd write code to sort the object properties by key, then use JSON.stringify and store a hash of that string. I'd store hashes and object references in a Map object for fast lookup when examining hashes of subsequent items